# Open Android SDK Manager from Eclipse as an admin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

My Problem: If I don´t open my SDK Manager as an Admin, I can´t download the new updates. (Error) So I always went in the sdk dictionary and then I run it as admin.

But how can I run the SDK Manager as an Admin, when I want to start it from Eclipse without going into the dictionary?

Comment: Windows User: Goto SDK folder, where you have extracted your SDK .. Right click on SDK and Run As Administrator...

Btw SDK should download data in normal case too..

Comment: You want to be careful about running IDEs as a special user - depending on the details, this can result in temporary or build artifact files getting left behind which cannot be cleaned up by your normal user account, leading to puzzling error messages.  Why not launch the SDK Manager independently when you want to do an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about right-clicking on the SDK Manager.exe, selecting "Properties", then switch to the "Compatibility" tab and checking "Run this program as administrator"? That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Eclipse as Administrator. That should do the trick.

In order to do so, right click on Eclipse shortcut and then on Shortcut tab, click on Advanced options and check "Execute as admin"